# Fixed position element to respect min-width of body

Tags: html, css

Is it possible have fixed-position items respect a minimum width for the document?

For example, I imagine something like the below example (which does not do what I want). The square is aligned to the right of the page (right:0), but does not respect the min-width of the document.

Is there a way to make this work with fixed-position items? Of course this could be accomplished with absolutely positioned items contained in the appropriate parent element, but many complex websites make use of fixed positioned elements (for various reasons) that should presumably also be able to take into account a minimum size of the containing document...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        min-width: 1000px; /* this doesn't do what I want */
      }
      div.rightalign {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="rightalign"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see your problem. This is how a fixed element acts. It goes all the way to the right of the viewport and stays there fixed, even when you scroll. And your min-width works, it's minimum 1000px width.

Comment: what aren't you setting the `<div>` to `width: "100%"` if you want it to take the full width of the container?

Comment: Yes, I know that's how fixed position works. I'm asking if there is a way to have it respect a minimum viewport width.

In my example above I am hoping that if the user's viewport is 500px, the right side of the blue box is still stuck at 1000px since the minimum viewport width is 1000px.

Comment: You seem to have viewport width confused with the width of an element. If you set the `min-width` of the containing element to `1000px` and the `width` of the inner element to `100%`, then it should accomplish what I think you want. If not, I'm afraid I don't understand your goal.